# How do I work out the use-by dates for my own cooking?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation

If I sort my fridge by 'eat by' date, what is the best way of dealing with food's I've cooked, or partially cooked, myself?

In my fridge there are such delights as:

- thrawed from frozen strawberries for the baby
- Seiten loaf, made in the last day
- several different types of leftovers.

...and it occurs to me I don't know how to work out the 'eat by' dates on any of the dishes we've made ourselves.

I'd like to know some good rules: excellent answers might include: "I run a bakery and this is the situation that the FDA told us we had to go by" but I'll take any information there is...

Answer (score 11):

The US FDA has a handy [Refrigerator and Freezer Storage Chart](https://www.fda.gov/downloads/food/resourcesforyou/healtheducators/ucm109315.pdf) that might help you.  In general your "leftovers" have a 3 to 4 day shelf life...I would think that includes your thawed strawberries.

Comment: Although I would probably err on the side of caution where food for a baby is involved, especially with soft and spoilage-prone food like strawberries.

Comment: This is very much what I asked for, thank you - don't suppose you happened to find a pdf that wasn't quite so... meaty?